# Reserve GPU for one exclusive OpenCL host programme

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

Is there a possibility to exclusively reserve the GPU for an OpenCL host programme?

No other process shall have access to this device via OpenCL or OpenGL.

Background is that my software calculates real time data on the GPU and therefore it's not good for the performance if the GPU is doing other stuff as well.

Comment: You cannot do that, impossible. The OpenCL standard allows you to queue things to the GPU, but never to possess it for you only. The only possible way, is to have a dedicated GPU that is not being used by other apps. (Secondary GPU)

Comment: If you don't connect a display then it won't be used for the desktop composition. That's generically about as close as you can get to what you want. NVIDIA hardware has a mode that makes it "compute only", which is even closer. However, there is no way to ensure no other application doesn't also try to do compute. You'll need to lock down the machine environment to ensure that.

Comment: You can't reserve it explicitly, but if you allocate all the global and local memory on it, then you will effectively prevent any other programs from running on it.